# Not going to onMessageRecieved when the app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using push notifications and they work fine when i am inside the app. But when app is in background . When notification arrives , i need it to go to onMessageRecieved because i am setting a condition like :

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    String type = data.getString("type");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    Log.d(TAG, "Type: " + type);
    sendNotification(message, type);
}
private void sendNotification(String message, String type) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    //Set all notifcation properties etc

    if (type.equals(Constants.GROUP_NOTIFICATION)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Keys.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, Constants.QUESTION_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
}
}
```

For question Push Notification when it comes to the mainactivity by checking intent data it shoud be redirected to the questionActivity but since intent data is never set , it stays in mainactivity.
So my question is , how do i get data from the notification?

Comment: you are using GCM service ?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Well since i didn't get answers on my post so i figured out the problem my self . Did some searching and found out that there are two types of payloads. Data and notification . And if u have the notification payload than if your app is in background . Android will create a notification itself and will not called onMEssageRecieved . So i went to my server code and simply removed the notification payload part :) and now onMessagerecieved gets called.